# How to reapply for Canadian working visa (IEC) after rejection due to not submitting a document?

Tags: working-visas, immigration, canada, working-holiday-visas, forms

I have applied under one of my nationalities that had more favourable applicants/spots ratio. I received the invitation and have **completed and submitted the application to my knowledge**.

My issue came with having to submit form IMM5257B stating past countries I have been to. I have filled in the form and submitted it, website was very buggy and I couldn't initially submit it so I stated my problem in the communication form and sent along with the IMM5257B form.

Few days later I got a message saying that the form has not been submitted and to resubmit it with additional 5 years worth of visited countries. Letter stated that:

`Failure to provide said document or a status update of your efforts to acquire said document, will result in your application being refused.`

Now here I should have gotten the clue that something wasn't correct, but I brushed it aside and assumed that the wording was unimportant and simply they just required it resubmitted (rather than submitted) with additional countries that I have visited.

So I did it all again, and to my surprise I got a message yesterday that my application has been rejected due to not submitting the IMM5257B form. This had me baffled as I was sure I logged in and uploaded the updated document. I have messaged them via the portal stating what happened again and how I believe I have submitted everything, but I assume such immigration decisions are usually final and when they are not it's because a lawyer is involved. At the end it stated that:

`You are welcome to reapply if you feel that you can respond to these concerns and can demonstrate that your situation meets the requirements. All new applications must be accompanied by a new processing fee.`

1. Is there a known mechanism of contacting someone who is part of the immigration visa approval process and can look into me having actually at least sent them a message with the required document?

Assuming I'm just an idiot and each time I just didn't press some sneaky hidden submit button on a totally not glitchy page not suffering from random downtime, I still have submitted a request stating my problem with the portal and attached the needed form.

2. Can I reapply again and pay again or is would that require me getting another invitation to apply, as this one is already lost?

I don't mind paying that hefty fee once more, but this would likely be impossible, as you get only one invitation per nationality per season.

3. If that's the case could I reapply with another one of my citizenships?

I would like to get IEC as soon as possible and I'm curious whether that is an allowed maneuver. I failed at getting the visa on one passport so I could reapply with another passport **in the same** yearly window. Something has changed for that country's pool and there is a lot of spaces so I'd say I am guaranteed to get a place.

To resubmit it with secondary citizenship I would have to withdrew the application that I initially got invited under, if the request I have sent out actually reached someone and it was indeed a system error and I might be given another opportunity to provide the IMM5257B form, guess it wouldn't make a difference since I voluntarily pulled out while waiting to be contacted.

Sorry if my thoughts are a little bit over the show, this whole thing took me by surprise.

Comment: Q1 - who are you asking to look into the submission problem? It’s not likely to be something TSE can help with

Comment: I fixed it to be more meaningful, i didn't mean to imply that someone here can look up at my application.